# Json parse from URL

Tags: java, android

I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException when I run this. Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Please take a look at my code and let me know if you have any suggestions.

```
{"begin":[{"id":1,"name":"Andy","size":1}],"open":[{"id":1,"name":"Tom","size":2}]}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    public MainFragment() {}

    //URL to get JSON Array
    private String url = "URL...";

    //JSON Node Names
    private static final String TAG_BEGIN = "begin";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_SIZE = "size";

    JSONArray begin = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        new JSONParse().execute();

        return rootView;
    }

    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(HomeActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                // Getting JSON Array
                begin = json.getJSONArray(TAG_BEGIN);
                JSONObject c = begin.getJSONObject(0);

                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String size = c.getString(TAG_SIZE);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**JSONParser**

```
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

**Error:**

```
E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

FATAL EXCEPTION: main

java.lang.NullPointerException
at
...$MainFragment$JSONParse.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:399)
at
...$MainFragment$JSONParse.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:373)
```

Which is...

```
begin = json.getJSONArray(TAG_BEGIN);
```

and...

```
private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
```

**EDIT (Answer)**

**JSONParser**

Inside of JSONParser I changed my code to this:

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(url);
        request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();

        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

**Inside of onPostExecute**

```
JSONArray begin = json.getJSONArray(TAG_BEGIN);
 for (int i = 0; i < begin(); i++) {
  try {

   JSONObject b = = begin(i);

   String id = b.getString(TAG_ID);
   String name = b.getString(TAG_NAME);
   String size = b.getString(TAG_SIZE);

  } catch (JSONException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
```

Comment: Just a side note. If you use Google Volley, it will help you alot!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Do you know how to solve my problem without using Google Volley?

Comment: You code looks alright. I assume that your json object returned by doInBackground is null. Maybe no network connection?

Comment: @NobuGames I do have a network connection. I thought of that already.

Comment: My suggestion is you can parse the JSON in clientside and send that data to serverside that is pretty easier and preferable way to do

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your JSONObject is not null. Then slowly transverse line by line based off the type.

```
JSONArray begin = json.getJSONArray(TAG_BEGIN);
```

Then possibly do something like this?

```
for(int n = 0; n < begin.length(); n++)
{
    JSONObject object = begin.getJSONObject(n);
    // query through the array
    String id = object.getString(TAG_ID);
    String name = object.getString(TAG_NAME);
    String size = object.getString(TAG_SIZE);
    //Now do something with the strings
}
```

Of course you'd do the same thing with the TAG_OPEN. Let me know if this works, I'll gladly help as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it and am still getting the same error.

Comment: Have you checked your "json" object from
 
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) { ... } 

if it's null?

Comment: How would I do that? I added JSONParser to my question. Maybe the problem is coming from that?

Comment: Just like this? if(json == null) {
                    
                } When I show json in a toast it returns as null.

Comment: As you're debugging, look at your "json" object in your watch/locals tab to determine if it's null when it's passed to the method I posted above in comments. Otherwise you have issues grabbing the json request in the first place and should re-look how you're grabbing it.

Comment: I am also getting this error E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Answer (score 0):

the error shows that the return string of you http request is not only the json data

something like  `<!DOCTYPE` are includeed

please check you are request the right url, and the server handle the request correctly

you can use your browser visit the url you request and check the return result

Comment: When I do visit the URL in my browser I get the same result {"begin":[{"id":1,"name":"Andy","size":1}],"open":[{"id":1,"name":"Tom","size":2}]}

Answer (score 0):

I am not using a fragment but here is similar solution.

Change your url and key values for retrieving values from json. I didn't have your url so i used some other. Please check it out. Same concept except i am not using fragments but this json parsing code works just fine.

First of all, you have to deal with the network on main thread exception

Add:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

in your class,

and

ADD this to ManiFestFile:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

MainActivity.Java

```
    package com.example.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Making HTTP request
        String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        try {
            // Getting JSON Array
            JSONArray begin = json.getJSONArray("contacts");
            JSONObject c = begin.getJSONObject(0);

            // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
            String id = c.getString("id");
            String name = c.getString("name");
            String size = c.getString("email");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

JSONParser.Java

```
package com.example.test;

import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```